# Add tags next to the question in list of hot questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hot-questions

Clicking on the StackExchange icon pops list of hot questions (sorted by votes). For example like this :
[image: Example of a list]

It would be great to add list of tags next to the site. If not possible all tags, then only the mostly used tags from the list in the question.

The reason I am asking this is that lots of time I see a question with lots of votes, but it is for some field that I am not interested at all. Seeing flags, I could easier filter out what I really want to see. The question's title is usually not enough to tell, unless it contain one of flags (I see that people sometimes put c, or c++ in the title).

Comment: can we also add the site specific logo on the Hot Questions tab? The other sections in the global inbox have them, and it makes it a lot easier to visually identify which questions I might care about.

Comment: Given that high ranked questions often leave out crucial information which can instead be found in the tags, it would be great to add this feature. "How do I X?" is unintelligible on Stack Overflow without knowing what language the person is asking about...

Comment: Very needed feature. And as shown here, there is enough space for it on the right of the name of the site. (It's especially useful for some sites: ex: hot questions coming for "gaming" usually ask a question about a specific game which name appears in the tag)

Comment: @qntmfred There is already the ste specific link underneath the question, so a logo would inform a user twice of what site it is. In addition, some SE sites don't seem to have a logo, just the little talk balloon with initials, which is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

With the upcoming [top bar redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign), this request is unfortunately going to become obsolete. We have a few other ideas for hot questions, but it's too early to tell if there would be room for tags in whatever the new display location and design end up being.