# Show tags in StackExchange dropdown

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add tags next to the question in list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113664/add-tags-next-to-the-question-in-list-of-questions)

For some questions, it's difficult to tell what the question is about without knowing what the tags are. For example, many questions on the gaming site only mention the name of the game in the tags.

[image]

This question is about the game League Of Legends, but you'd never guess that, looking at it from the dropdown.

How about putting the tags as title text for each question? Like this:

[image]