# Show Tags in HNQ Sidebar

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, hot-questions, sidebar

<sup>Old related post from 8 years ago: [Add tags next to the question in list of hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113664/232439)</sup>

As of now, there's no way to see the tags on a Hot Network question in the sidebar without clicking into it.

We already show the name of the site the question is hosted on when the site icon on the left is hovered over.

Could we add similar hover-text to the title link that will show the tags? Something like:

```
[feature-request], [tags], [design], [hot-questions], [sidebar]
```

Especially on sites like Movies & TV, Arqade and SciFi.SE, this would allow users to easily check whether or not the question is about something that interests them without being forced to click in for more context about the title.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with userscripts, this feature has already been implemented in [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

[image]

Upon installing SOX, you'll need to enable the "Filter the hot network questions by their attributes" option and click on **Save Changes**. There are plenty of other useful SOX features too; do check them out! However, a drawback is that enabling too many features will noticeably slow down the webpages. So choose the ones you really need.

Comment: Hey, thanks for using SOX. I'm one of its developers and I've been trying to make it more efficient/work better recently -- would you mind posting on stack apps or on github which features you find make the pages load slower? I'd really like to improve it! :)